# IBM Rational Application Developer JDK error when starting

Tags: eclipse, java, ibm-rad

Hi i installed IBM RAD on win7 32 bit edition.

After launching RAD it gives an error

Could not find the main class:
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.support.LibraryDetector.
Program will exit

And later

Could not find the main class
Program will exit

How can i fix this.

Note :I tried to install ibm rad on ubuntu it does not start there too.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is not supported, even in RAD 8. For Windows 7 support, you need RAD 7.5.5. If, as you indicate in a comment, you're running RAD 7.5, that's not a supported configuration.

See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=2042&uid=swg21327294) for the platform support statements for RAD.

In other words, you need to upgrade to RAD 7.5.5 at a minimum.

Comment: my friend says that he installed successfully :S

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, your friend isn't IBM. All I can do is point you to the statement of support. If you choose to ignore that, that's up to you. There's usually a good reason why they say things like that. It's either because the fix wasn't backported to earlier versions or that the specific version was the one where they fixed the reported bug. In either case, running 7.5.4 is a bad idea. If you can get it running, more power to you, but it's _still_ not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation is broken.  Uninstall it and try again without any deviation from what the installation manager suggests.

Comment: i did it at least three times

Comment: I have had issues with the installation manager under Windows 7 with other products.  IBM.com does not answer right now - is Windows 7 supported for your RAD 7.5 product?  If not, consider running it in XP Mode.  I've had to do that for WSDCi.